# Is it possible to build dynamic LINQ queries to non-strongly type datatables?

Tags: linq, dynamic-linq

Using [LINQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query), I've been trying to use the System.Linq.Dynamic library in order to query a datatable dynamically. The problem is that it's not strongly typed, and the extension method for  select is expecting an IEnumerable as the source.

Is there a way to work around this? Example code:

```
var query = dataSet.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select("new(Regional)");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution here. I know this approach is might not be good when talking about performance, but it works for what I want

[HOW TO: Implement a DataSet GROUP BY Helper Class in Visual C# .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326145)

Comment: I don't see anything in your linq refers to using Dynamic Linq on a loosely typed datatable.

Answer (score 0):

`AsEnumerable` returns an `EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow>`, so the `Select` extension method should work fine on the result of `AsEnumerable`...

For instance :

```
var query = dataSet.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(row => row.Field<string>("Regional"));
```

Comment: I know that. But you have to specify the datatype and the field in order to do so. That way I can't build the query dynamically using a string.